# Selecting out numbers contained in a commonly formatted line

Tags: java, regex

This is my pattern:

```
Pattern.compile( "^(.+?)([A-Z]+?)([\\.\\s\\.]+?)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)" );
```

If I pass through this line, I get what I am looking for (`12.0`):

```
STAT WBC . . . . . . . . . .  12.0     H          (3.5-11.0)      X10(9)/L
```

However, if I pass through this line (where I intend to not retrieve any number), I get `14`:

```
GENERIC HOSPITAL, TX                                       14 Feb 2018@1143
```

As another example, this line returns `30` (which I do not want):

```
NAME, FAKE                   30/50  SSN: 123456789     Rec #: 123456
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to return `labType` and `labValue` from a `String` passed through. For the first example, I can get the `12.0` back. I would assign this to `labValue`. I would like to assign `WBC` to `labType`, however I have not figured that out yet.

There are many lines that come in the `.txt` print out of a patient's labs. All the lines I care about though have a similar format:

`. . . . .`

They all include the string `. .` at least once. The `labType` comes right before this repeating string (as `WBC` in the example above). Sometimes `STAT` or empty `\\s` (whitespace) appear before the `labType` - I don't want this included in my `labType`. The `labValue` always comes right after the repeating string (as `12.0` does in the example above). Anything after this number (and some have decimals, some do not), I do not care about.

Here are some additional examples of the lines with `labType` and `labValue` contained within:

```
 MCV . . . . . . . . . .  79.6     L           (80-100)       fL
 MCH . . . . . . . . . .  28.0                 (26-34)        pg
 MCHC. . . . . . . . . .  35.2                 (32-36)        g/dL
 RDW . . . . . . . . . .  18.4     H         (11.5-14.5)      %
 PLATELETS . . . . . .   539       H          (150-440)       X10(9)/L
 MPV . . . . . . . . . .   9.2     L          (9.4-12.3)      fL
 GRANULO/100 . . . . . .  69.1               (42.2-75.2)      %
 LYMPH/100 WBC . . . . .  21.1     L           (22-44)        %
 MONO/100 WBC. . . . . .   5.7                  (0-10)        %
 EOS/100 WBC . . . . . .   2.7                  (0-5)         %
 BASO/100 WBC. . . . . .   0.3                  (0-3)         %
 NEUT# . . . . . . . . .  11.16    H          (1.5-7.5)       X10(9)/L
 LYMPH#. . . . . . . . .   3.4                (1.0-4.8)       X10(9)/L
 MONO# . . . . . . . . .   0.9     H            (0-0.8)       X10(9)/L
 EOS#. . . . . . . . . .   0.44                 (0-.45)       X10(9)/L
```

Here are some examples of other "distractor" lines:

```
PLASMA
Performing Lab: GENERIC LAB
111111 ABC 222              
Order comment:  ONETIME
```

I feel like I am on the cusp of figuring this out, but I have only just started with regex. Am I way off?

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to match. `labType` is supposed to be the string of capital letters that precedes the `. . .` and `labValue` is the number that immediately follows it? Lines without dots should be ignored completely?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: What about the lines that start with strings like `GRANULO/100` or `LYMPH/100 WBC`? What part of those is the lab type?

Comment: `GRANULO/100` would be the lab type. The only thing before the `. . .` that is not a `labType` is when the word `STAT` would appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. This regex should provide what you need:

```
^(?:STAT\s|\s+)(.*?)(?:\s\.|\.){2,}(?:[\s\.]*)(\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pb3iOu/4)

Comment: Vertical bars are literals within square brackets, not alternation.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer works and the difference in output is subtle compared to the answer below. Your regex outputs  white space before the `labType` (such as `HGB`), whereas @Gurman regex outputs `Type = HGB Value = 7.5` with no whitespace prior to the `labType`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Pb3iOu/3 <- Do you know why the regex in this case is selecting the lines at the bottom after `GFR-AA`?

Comment: It's because of the dot. I have updated my regex, it now works with the link you provided. :). It now checks if the formatted line has at least 2 dots in the middle. `{2,}`

Comment: Thank you! Regex is incredible. I need to learn it well. Any recommendations?

Comment: Just practice it. Regex101 is fantastic for quickly testing your Regexes. As for documentation and such I recommend these sites: [RegEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html) or [Regular-Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
^\s*(?:STAT\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s*\.)+\s*(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pb3iOu/2/)**

**[See the JAVA output here](http://rextester.com/VODCE53097)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `(?:STAT\s*)?` - matches the word `STAT` followed by 0+ occurrences of a whitespace. The `?` in the end makes this part optional.
- `(.*?)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline, as few as possible and capture it in group 1. Group 1 now contains the **labType**
- `(?:\s*\.)+` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace followed by a `.`. The `+` at the end attempts to match this sub-sequence 1 or more times
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)` - matches 0+ occurrences of a digit followed by optional - `.` followed by 1+ digits. Capture this whole match in group 2. Group 2 now contains the **labValue**

Comment: This is great. Where did you learn regex so well? The JavaDoc for Pattern is not helping me.

Comment: I am not that good with regexes. Still learning. I practice it here only on Stack overflow by answering the questions. There is one great website too. Here is the [LINK](http://www.rexegg.com/)